# Dynamoose TypeError

Tags: node.js, dynamoose

I am running into a weird issue with dynamoose... The stack is as below:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'attributeTypes')

The errors happens in the following function of Item.js:

```
static isDynamoObject(object, recursive) {
    function isValid(value) {
        if (typeof value === "undefined" || value === null) {
            return false;
        }
        const keys = Object.keys(value);
        const key = keys[0];
        const nestedResult = typeof value[key] === "object" && !(value[key] instanceof Buffer) && !(value[key] instanceof Uint8Array) ? Array.isArray(value[key]) ? value[key].every((value) => Item.isDynamoObject(value, true)) : Item.isDynamoObject(value[key]) : true;
        const { Schema } = require("./Schema");
        const attributeType = Schema.attributeTypes.findDynamoDBType(key);
        return typeof value === "object" && keys.length === 1 && attributeType && (nestedResult || Object.keys(value[key]).length === 0 || attributeType.isSet);
    }
    const keys = Object.keys(object);
    const values = Object.values(object);
    if (keys.length === 0) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        return recursive ? isValid(object) : values.every((value) => isValid(value));
    }
}
```

it returns the following as undefined:

```
        const { Schema } = require("./Schema");
```

It works for one model but not for other. I am new to TypeScript and Dynamoose but pretty clueless about why it would fail to load this module only in certain situations.

Expecting Schema to be loaded... I wrote an integration test and within the same integration test, it works fine when I query one model by Id, but fails when I try to do the same for other model.